# HTML: li and a href

Tags: html

So i have styled my ul li, it comes in a dropdown box and when you mark over each li it a:hover with purple. Now in each li there´s a name. I want to make it all a link, so when you click anywhere in the marked li you go to the link.

Right now, when you click somewhere in the li nothing happens, only if you click on the name IN the li..

Here's my code:

```
  echo '<a href="profil.php?id='.$result->id.'"><li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->full_name).'\');">'.$result->full_name.'</li></a>';
```

How do i do this?

```
    .suggestionsBox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
    margin: 26px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 200px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-top: 3px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.suggestionList {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.suggestionList ul li {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 6px;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #5a2156;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.suggestionList ul li:hover {
    background-color: #5a2156;
    color:#000;
}
ul {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `A` element can only contain level elements and `LI` is only allowed in `OL` and `UL`. But `LI` allows `A` inside, so make it the other way round:

```
echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->full_name).'\');"><a href="profil.php?id='.$result->id.'">'.$result->full_name.'</a></li>';
```

To make the `A` fill the available space, display it as block element:

```
li > a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem; but regardless an `li` can only be a child of a `ol` or `ul`.

Comment: Using <a> inside <li> is proper. To ensure the link appears the same as the other list elements, consider the following CSS:

li > a {
    display: block;
    font-weight:inherit!important;
    font-family:inherit!important;
    color:inherit!important;
    text-decoration:inherit!important;
}

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but for those who have the same problem:

I would (and did) it like so:

```
.suggestionList ul li {
list-style:none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border-bottom:1px dotted #5a2156;
cursor: pointer;
}
.suggestionList ul li a {
display: block;
padding: 6px;
}
```

The li element has no more padding, and the a inside is as big as the li element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should put an `<li>` inside an anchor `<a>` like that. If you want the whole line to be clickable just put the `<a>` inside of the `<li>` and it should take up the right width. if not, give it a set height and width and the `<li>` should fit tightly around it, making it all clickable.

so like:

```
echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->full_name).'\');"><a href="profil.php?id='.$result->id.'">'.$result->full_name.'</a></li>';
```

and then the css:

```
a{height : 20px;}
```

`<a>` is inline so its width cannot be set but it will wrap tightly around it's text.

Answer (score 0):

First, a `li` element must be a direct child of a `ul` element, so you have to have the `a` tag inside the `li` tags.

Here is how I would construct the HTML / CSS; incorporate it into your php however you think it would work best.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="list1">Content 1</span></a></li>
</ul>

.list1 {width: 120px;} /* Set this to whatever width you want the list to fill*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using on my project and it works great. The overflow stops the **a href** from expanding outside of the li and 100% padding fills the space.

```
#cbtn li
{
    height: 61px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#cbtn li a
{
    padding: 100%;
    outline: none;
}
```

Example of it working: http://jsbin.com/ilocow/4/